# How to improve graphical performance of Windows 8 on KVM?

Tags: windows-8, linux-kvm

I installed Windows 8 on KVM. But its graphical performance is less than desirable.

First I tried to use SPICE protocol to solve this problem, but it doesn't support Windows 8.

Next I tried to use Vmware VGA Driver introduced in [Using Vmware VGA with KVM Windows Guests](http://www.linux-kvm.com/content/using-vmware-vga-kvm-windows-guests). But the driver which we can download in the above article also doesn't support Windows 8.

Do anyone have any idea how to improve Windows 8 graphical performance on KVM?